# How to find a rails object based on a date value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `User` object and I am attempting to do 2 different queries as part of a script that needs to run nightly. Given the schema below I would like to:

- Get all the Users with a non nil `end_date`
- Get all the Users with an `end_date` that is prior to today (I.E. has passed)

**Users Schema:**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                            :integer          not null, primary key
#  name                          :string(100)      default("")
#  end_date                      :datetime
```

I've been trying to use `User.where('end_date != NULL)` and other things but I cannot seem to get the syntax correct.

Comment: You want AND or OR ? :p I am confused..

Comment: He said two different queries.

Comment: Which version of Rails do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your methods should be as below inside the `User` model :

```rb
def self.users_with_end_date_not_null
  self.where.not(end_date: nil)
  # below Rails 4 use
  # self.where("end_date != ?", nil)
end

def self.past_users n
  self.where(end_date: n.day.ago)
end
```

Comment: Note that the query method `.not` requires at least Rails 4.

Comment: @SebastianvomMeer Done,,, below version

Comment: @SebastianvomMeer What was the problem due to which syntax highlighting was not happening ?

Comment: You can specify a language before a code block, when SO doesn't detect it correctly: `<!-- language: ruby -->` http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints

Comment: @SebastianvomMeer Ok,, what you have added which made it perfect.. :)